# SimpleMembershipProvider - password encryption

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, encryption

I am using SimpleMembershipProvider as my database provider.

I already have added new functions to improve this provider through inherit.

Now I want to create a function like "ChangeEmail" but before this check that inputted password is correct.

So I must encrypt inputted password and compare result to entry in my database.

The question is:

**In what way SimpleMembershipProvider encrypts password?**

I tried:

```
Crypto.HashPassword(currentPassword);
```

The result was similar but not the same like this in database.

PasswordFormat property is set to MembershipPasswordFormat.Hashed.

For example, hash for "123456" generated while registration:

```
AIYlAKcmDaABMw1PVx1kheZq2KXkhVs4QjO7MnwfHPcTBjnmRobRqJzWYHYO/S4T7w==
```

And this via Crypto.HashPassword:

```
AG+md+0W2EuV9BzUdohkYMK547jB5ochvxeVKYQTkls0UQ+3W0BWPHnFoffiIn2byw==
```

It looks like the same type of encoding but why results are different?

Comment: What do you have set for the [`PasswordFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.passwordformat.aspx) property? That determines how the password is stored.

Comment: @adrianbanks MembershipPasswordFormat.Hashed

Comment: If `Crypto.HashPassword` doesn't suck completely, it'll return a different password on each call.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Ohh, true, thanks! I just need to use Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword. Maybe you will write it as answer that I can mark your post as "correct"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Crypto.HashPassword` generates a new salt for each call, so the output will be different each time. To verify use `Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword`.

Alternatively use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` directly. That allows you to tune the hashing cost, and it can avoid using hashes larger than the native size(20 bytes).